# Conda activate env by deactivate the currrent env

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

Is it possible to activate one **env** by deactivating the current **env**?

For example I use my **env1**:

```
(env1) user@computer:~$
```

For the moment to pass to another **env** I use:

```
conda deactivate; conda activate other_env
```

Is there a way to activate an **env** by deactivating the current **env**?

I asked this because for instance if you are on the **env1** and you activate **env2** without deactivate **env1**, **env1** is still active:

```
(env1) user@computer:~$ conda activate env2
(env2) user@computer:~$ conda deactivate env2
(env1) user@computer:~$
```

Comment: Your above example looks like a rather convenient feature, but if this really "can bring some problems" (without being more specific than that),  it would contradict the whole virtual environment idea. I really doubt that.

Comment: I don't remember exactly how I encountered problems but I will try to reproduce and edit the question.

Comment: Technically, the default behavior of `conda activate` is to deactivate any currently active environments before activating the requested one. But it does track what envs were previously active, so they are reactivated after the new env deactivates. It seems to me you don’t want Conda to reactivate previous envs when calling `conda deactivate`. Is that correct? Something like a `conda deactivate --all` option?

Comment: I don't managed to reproduce the problem I encountered. I edited the question and delete "it can bring some problems". I probably did a bad handling. If i encounter the problem again I will edit the question but for the moment I prefer to delete the sentence. Than you for you comment @Peter!

Comment: @merv: It is almost what I want. However, in the best, I prefer to just use `conda activate`. I see that there are a "stack" but I don't understand how to manage it.